# How much do question titles matter?

Tags: discussion

We receive a lot of traffic from Stack Overflow usually from [hot network question](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) listings. Sometimes that referral traffic correlates with our [most popular questions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). However, other times referral traffic seems to be highly correlated with funny question titles.

Quality content, is of utmost importance, but clever titles do seem to help generate traffic. Both of the questions below appeared in the [hot network question](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) list at some point and I have to believe that their title was part of the reason.

[What are Fluffy Blocks?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2633/7) **1426 visits in the first 2 days**

[My dog ate the USB key with 10000 monero wallet. Are they lost forever?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2004/7) **709 visits**